# How to lock a database row using JPA until another table is updated

Tags: java, database, jpa

I am new to JPA using Hibernate/Spring. My use case is:

I have 2 tables - `A` and `B`. When the user queries table `A` and gets a row, it should be locked and won't be issued to anyone else until the user is done doing some operation using the returned data and updated table `B`.

I can add a column (say `IS_LOCKED`) in table `A` and then update it once the operation is complete. But I am trying to figure out if there is a better solution to this problem. Not sure if the `javax.persistence.LockModeType` is of much use in this case.

Comment: What do you mean with 'some operations'? Can you give an example? JavaEE and JPA create a transaction at a REST call for example, so the row would be part of the transaction.

Comment: @kedenk e.g. get flight number from FLIGHTS table and update the reference in BOOKING table. Let's assume FLIGHTS table won't be updated.

Comment: And these two operations are performed within one REST call? As mentioned before, JavaEE and JPA create a transaction at a call. So you should be saved with that and don't need an explicit lock. But if you want to set a specific log, the first answer helps you.

Comment: I am not doing any REST call here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with `Hibernate` and with `LockModeType`.

There are many possibilities based on your needs, so the best way is to choose from [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/).